# error while running face recognize program

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

While running face recognition program using OpenCV vr 1.0 I am getting a error commands like unsupported format or combination of formats (unsupported combination of input/output formats) in function `cvConvertImage`.

But I am not using this function in my program, so please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

somehow, other opencv functions might call this function as well.
could you provide more code when you get this error?

some opencv function accept certain kinds of inpur image format only.
if your are trying to convert the image to other format, make sure whether opencv support this or not.